# How would one configure a Hyper-V switch such that the host machine shares an adapter with the virtual machines?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm looking to configure a Hyper-V Vm in such a way that the VMs are given an IP on the same subnet as the host machine, which would make networking much easier.

My basic layout looks something like so:

[image]

Note that I do not want to use NAT for this operation, I want IPs to be leased through the PHY adapter, just as an Ethernet switch would. The subnet can be inherited from the Virtual switch to the PHY adapter at a 1:1 ratio (I.E. the virtual switch has exclusive access to the PHY adapter). The host machine would then connect through the virtual switch, just as the VMs would.

How would this be accomplished with the Hyper-V network management tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the virtual switch to "External network" mode and choose the physical Ethernet interface to attach it to. This is already enough to directly bridge the VMs to the physical network.

[image: Screenshot of Hyper-V "Virtual Switch Manager"]

Then make sure to enable the option "Allow management OS to share this network adapter". This will create a virtual interface connecting the host OS to the virtual switch.

[image: Screenshot of Network Adapters control panel]